# Why can't I assume there has to be an extremum?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Today I got a scan of an final exam I did in calculus. Luckily, I passed, but I couldn't help noticing that I lost **many** points in my answers over things there weren't false, but misexplained(seemed too trivial to me): Suppose I have found a minimum (of a continuous function)that is under the x-axis, and when $x$ tends to $\pm \infty$ the function tends to infinity. That means there are at least two solutions (cuts) by the intermediate value theorem. To show there can't be any more solutions, I looked at what happens between $x_1$(left cut) and $-\infty$, $c$(minimum) and $x_2$(right cut.), I mean, I looked at: $-\infty<x<x_1$, $x_1<x<c$, $c<x<x_2$, and $x_2<x<\infty$.

Let us take, for instance $x_1<x<c$: I said that if there is another points where the function cuts the x-axis, there would have to be another extremum, which there isn't, and therefore, in that domain, there is no additional solution. That was barely admissible. What explanation could I have provided that would be acceptable by calculus theorems and claim? I would appreciate your reply.

Comment: Did you prove that there is no other extremum?

Comment: Not really. I did remember that once you have the points where the derivative vanishes, those are the only candidates... I am, however, not sure if it was said through highschool or lectures..

Comment: If you used derivative to check for extrema, you had to verify that the derivative is everywhere defined, because you can have an extremum at a point where function is not differentiable (e.g. take function $f(x)=|x|$).

Comment: This is incredibly vague... "there would have to be another extremum, *which there isn't*": what? Where did that come from? Can you include the full problem statement? Because as it is, it's difficult to tell you what is wrong. Anyway, if you think something is "too trivial", then surely it's easy to prove and the proof isn't very long, so there's no problem with including the proof. If that's not the case, that thing isn't "too trivial".

Answer (score 0):

in problem solving there are two phases, which to some extent overlap in thought. there is the intuitive phase, and a more careful phase. intuition can leap forward, but also tends to smuggle in convenient assumptions which may be misleading, unproven or even wrong. hence the need for careful checking, which is often assisted by some reliable symbolic representation.

here (although your statement of the problem is unacceptably vague as it stands), you have a useful intuition. how to make it somewhat more formal? why not begin by stating the problem clearly? that may give you valuable clues about how to proceed.